# Reading characted from string and getting an integer value

Tags: c

I have a string as follows:

```
char myString[] = "Amazing String";
```

I want to loop over the string and print characters as follows:

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0;i < sizeof(myString);i++){
    printf("%s\n", myString[i]);
}
```

But for some reason i get integer values instead of the character itself.

Sorry if this is a completely stupid question but i cant see what i am doing wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't use `sizeof` like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use [`strlen()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strlen) instead for the length of a string and you want to print characters (`%c`):

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0;i < strlen(myString);i++){  // to get a string's length, use strlen
    printf("%c\n", myString[i]);       // to print a single character, use %c
}
```

Why use `strlen()` over `sizeof()`? Well, in this particular instance, it won't make a difference; however `strlen()` is for giving you the number of printable characters in a string whereas `sizeof` will return the size of your array (printable characters + 1 for null terminator).

```
int len1 = sizeof(myString); // 15
int len2 = strlen(myString); // 14
```

A) you won't see that printed so it doesn’t help
B) if you get in the habit of using `sizeof` on strings you might use it within a function you pass your array to (in which case the array will decay to a pointer) and then you'll get back the size of a `char *` not the number of characters at all. Same applies within the same function if you had done `char *myString = "Amazing String";`

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `"%s"` symbol for strings when you should be using `"%c"` for single characters:

```
printf("%c\n", myString[i]);
//      ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i = 0;
for (i = 0;i < sizeof(myString);i++){
    printf("%c\n", myString[i]);
}
```

%c instead of %s  and sizeof() is not a good choice.  try `strlen(myString)`